# How do you traverseHierarchy (for LOD) in THREE.js r54?

Tags: three.js

I have taken a break from playing with THREE.js but have some time to experiment again and so I have updated my THREE.js build from r49 to r54 and have managed to update everything in my experiments but I'm having issues with LOD.

In r49 I used the following to traverse the scene hierarchy:

```
THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( scene, function ( node ) { if ( node instanceof THREE.LOD ) node.update( cameras[selectedCamera] ) } );
```

Now that generates a type error and informs me that THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy is not a function.

Checked the documentation for r54 but it's a little behind so has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading to the current version.

> Replaced SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy with object.traverse.

Comment: Ahh nice one, missed the migration wiki